# a problem of linearly independence between matrices

Tags: geometry

I have three matrices
$$\begin{Bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 0 & -1 \end{Bmatrix},\begin{Bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 \end{Bmatrix},\begin{Bmatrix} 2 & -2 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{Bmatrix} \in M_{2,3}(Q)$$
and I have to determine if they are linearly independent.

$$\alpha_1*\begin{Bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 0 & -1 \end{Bmatrix}+\alpha_2*\begin{Bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 1 \end{Bmatrix}+\alpha_3*\begin{Bmatrix} 2 & -2 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{Bmatrix}=\begin{Bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{Bmatrix}$$

$$\begin{Bmatrix} \alpha_1+\alpha_2+2*\alpha_3 & \alpha_1+\alpha_2-2*\alpha_3 & \alpha_1+\alpha_3 \\ 2*\alpha_1-\alpha_2+\alpha_3 & 0 & \alpha_1+\alpha_2 \end{Bmatrix}=\begin{Bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{Bmatrix}$$

$\left\{\begin{array}{l}\alpha_1+\alpha_2+2*\alpha_3=0\\\alpha_1+\alpha_2-2*\alpha_3=0\\\alpha_1+\alpha_3=0\\2*\alpha_1-\alpha_2+\alpha_3=0\\\alpha_1+\alpha_2=0\end{array}\right.$

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&2\\1&1&-2\\1&0&1\\2&-1&1\\1&1&0 \end{pmatrix}$$
Eliminating all the rows that are linearly combinations of the others, this matrix becomes
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}$$
The three initial matrices are independent but they aren't a base of $M_{2,3}(Q)$ because $dim_{M_{2,3}(Q)}=2*3=6$

I'm not sure if my attempt is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your attempt is correct. But you wrote that the 3 matrices are a base. That is  not true.